# Colab+MongoDB Atlas - Error: The "dnspython" module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:

Tags: google-colaboratory, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to run this tutoral of MongoDB in Google Colab:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/Giffy/MongoDB_PyMongo_Tutorial/blob/master/1_1_First_steps_with_MongoDB_PyMongo.ipynb

But when I try to change the URI to one mine, for example:

```
uri = 'mongodb+srv://asarova:asarova@cluster0.jtjfp.mongodb.net/prueba?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

I get the error

```
ConfigurationError: The "dnspython" module must be installed to use mongodb+srv:// URIs
```

Even after installing:

```
pip install pymongo[srv]
```

If I just erase "+srv", the block runs, but in the next one I get this other error

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster0.jtjfp.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
```

Do you have any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Try change **'mongodb+srv://'** to **'mongodb://'**. Works to me.

Answer (score 1):

In the Runtime tab select Restart runtime.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOG4v.png).
It worked for me!